# How to prevent Ubuntu from sleeping after remote reboot?

Tags: suspend, hibernate, reboot

First, thank you for your time reading this. I have a Ubuntu server and I disabled sleep/hibernate after I logged into the Ubuntu desktop. SSH and remote desktop worked fine. I remotely rebooted the server yesterday and found the server was back online several minutes after the rebooting. But it became offline today (cannot ssh, ping etc). I guess the reason is that the server went into sleep/hibernation (since I did not login with my account, the sleeping setting is not effective). Is there anyway to set the sleeping settings automatically during rebooting? Thanks.